# bug in filter with Symfony 4

Tags: symfony4

I'm creating a filter(for 'offre' entity) by departement ,experience, type(of contract) and a key word all the filters give the right result but experience I don't know why it doesn't respond however I make it alone without the other filter or with the problem I don't know where is the problem because it's a ChoiceType as ('type' attribut (with type of contract I don't have any problem))
here is the offreEmploi.php:

```
`<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Cocur\Slugify\Slugify;
use App\Entity\Candidat;

/**
 * OffreEmploi
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class OffreEmploi
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var titre
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $titre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", length=0, nullable=false)
     */
    private $description;
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="create_at", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $createAt;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="experience", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $experience;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date", nullable=false)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="remuneration", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $remuneration ;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="remarque", type="text", length=0, nullable=true)
     */
    private $remarque ;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="reponse", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $reponse ;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="etude_qualification", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $etudeQualification;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Metier", inversedBy="offreEmplois")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false,name="nom_metier",referencedColumnName="nom_metier")
     */
    private $metier;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Departement", inversedBy="offreEmplois")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false,name="code_departement", referencedColumnName="code_departement")
     */
    private $departement;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Entreprise", inversedBy="offres")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="email", referencedColumnName="email")
     */
    private $entreprise;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ApplyOffre", mappedBy="offre", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $applies;




    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->applies = new ArrayCollection();
    }



    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitre():?string
    {
        return $this->titre;
    }


    public function setTitre(string $titre): self
    {
        $this->titre = $titre;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreateAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createAt;
    }

    public function setCreateAt(\DateTimeInterface $createAt): self
    {
        $this->createAt = $createAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getExperience(): ?string
    {
        return $this->experience;
    }

    public function setExperience(?string $experience): self
    {
        $this->experience = $experience;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate(\DateTimeInterface $date): self
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRemuneration(): ?int
    {
        return $this->remuneration;
    }

    public function setRemuneration(?int $remuneration): self
    {
        $this->remuneration = $remuneration;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRemarque(): ?string
    {
        return $this->remarque;
    }

    public function setRemarque(?string $remarque): self
    {
        $this->remarque = $remarque;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getReponse(): ?string
    {
        return $this->reponse;
    }

    public function setReponse(?string $reponse): self
    {
        $this->reponse = $reponse;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEtudeQualification(): ?string
    {
        return $this->etudeQualification;
    }

    public function setEtudeQualification(?string $etudeQualification): self
    {
        $this->etudeQualification = $etudeQualification;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getMetier(): ?Metier
    {
        return $this->metier;
    }

    public function setMetier(?Metier $metier): self
    {
        $this->metier = $metier;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getSlug():string{
        return (new Slugify())->slugify($this->metier);
    }
    public function getDepartement(): ?Departement
    {
        return $this->departement;
    }

    public function setDepartement(?Departement $departement): self
    {
        $this->departement = $departement;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getType(): ?string
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType(?string $type): self
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEntreprise(): ?Entreprise
    {
        return $this->entreprise;
    }

    public function setEntreprise(?Entreprise $entreprise): self
    {
        $this->entreprise = $entreprise;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getTitre();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|ApplyOffre[]
     */
    public function getApplies(): Collection
    {
        return $this->applies;
    }

    public function addApply(ApplyOffre $apply): self
    {
        if (!$this->applies->contains($apply)) {
            $this->applies[] = $apply;
            $apply->setOffre($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeApply(ApplyOffre $apply): self
    {
        if ($this->applies->contains($apply)) {
            $this->applies->removeElement($apply);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($apply->getOffre() === $this) {
                $apply->setOffre(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

` 
and here is a part of  filterType as form :

'

```
<?php


namespace App\Form;


    use App\Entity\Departement;
    use App\Entity\Domaine;
    use App\Entity\Metier;
    use App\Entity\Region;
    use App\Entity\Type;
    use App\searchData\Filter;
    use App\searchData\OffreSearchBar;
    use App\searchData\OffreSearchSide;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

    class OffreFilterType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder


                    ->add('type', ChoiceType::class,[
                    'choices' =>[
                            'CDI'       =>'cdi',
                            'CDD'       =>'cdd',
                            'ALTERNANCE'=>'alternance',
                            'STAGE'     =>'Stage',
                            'CTT'       =>'CTT'


    >  ],
    >                 'required'=>false,
    >                 'multiple'=>true,
    >                 'expanded'=>true,
    >                 'label'   =>false
    >             ])
    > 
    > 
    >             ->add('experience', ChoiceType::class, [
    >                 'choices'=>[
    >                     'tout'=>'tout',
    >                     '<= 1 ans'=>'<=1 ans',
    >                     '1 à 3 ans'=>'1 à 3 ans',
    >                     'de 3 à 6 ans'=>'de 3 à 6 ans',
    >                     '+ de 5 ans'=>'+ de 5 ans'
    >                 ],
    >                 'required' => false,
    >                 'multiple'=>false,
    >                 'expanded'=>true,
    >                 'label' => false,
    >                 'placeholder'=>false
    >             ])
    >         ;
    >         }
    >     public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    >     {
    >         $resolver->setDefaults([
    >             'data_class' => Filter::class,
    >             'csrf_protection'=>false,
    >             'method'     =>'get'
    >         ]);
    >     } }
    ' 

and here is the repository: 

    public function  findSearch(Filter $data){
            $query=$this->createQueryBuilder('o');
            if($data->metier || $data->motCle || $data->type || $data->departement|| $data->experience){
                $query->join('o.metier','m')
                    ->join('o.departement','d')
                    ->addSelect('m')
                    ->addSelect('d')
                    //                  ->where('o.metier IN (:m)')
                    ->where(
                        $query->expr()->andX(
                             $query->expr()->andX(
                                    $query->expr()->eq('o.metier',':m'),
                                    $query->expr()->like('o.titre', $query->expr()->literal('%' . $data->motCle . '%'))
                             ),
                             $query->expr()->andX(
                                    $query->expr()->andX(
                                          $query->expr()->eq('o.type',':type'),
                                          $query->expr()->in('o.departement', (':d'))
                                    ),
                                   $query->expr()->andX(
                                       $query->expr()->eq('o.experience',':experience')
                                   )
                             )
                         )
                    )
                    ->setParameter('experience',$data->experience)
                    ->setParameter('d',$data->departement)
                    ->setParameter('m',$data->metier)
                    ->setParameter('type',$data->type);
            }

           return  $query->getQuery()->getResult();
        }
    }'
```

someone can tell me why the when I add the filter(experience) it don't give the right result and when I omet the

```
  `$query->expr()->andX(
       $query->expr()->eq('o.experience',':experience')
      )`
```

it works (it give the right result for the other filter) and even when I add it alone in an other query it give zero result

Comment: That nesting of andX is a bit messy. If you ony have `AND` cases you don't have to nest them. But to answer the question we need to now what is the value of `$data->experience` and what's in your DB.

Comment: It was a simple error in the EasyAdmin